# Using form helpers to picking an object by name, but assigning the ID associated with that name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Product` model, an `Order`, and an `OrderItem` model.
An `OrderItem` object has a single `Product` (that is, it `belongs to` a product)
An `Order` has multiple order items.

When you want to add an `OrderItem` to your order, you fill out a form. One of the fields is to enter the product that will be assigned to this order item. The order model stores the `product_id` as a foreign key, and so Rails complains (as it should) when I write

```
<%= form_for @orderItem, url: {:action => :create} do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :product_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :product_name %>
    </p>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What I have in mind is to to have someone use the form to create order items. When they choose which product to assign to this order item, they will pick a name from a list of product names (which are unique), and then when they submit the form, the controller retrieves the appropriate `Product` object and assigns its ID to the `OrderItem`.

How can I set up my form to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [**nested attributes**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). They'll let you save information about both an `OrderItem` and a `Product` at the same time from a single form.

In your `OrderItem`, add the line **`accepts_nested_attributes_for :product`**.

Then in your form you'll want something like:

```
<%= form_for @orderItem, url: {:action => :create} do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= fields_for :product do |fp| %>
        <%= fp.label :product_name %>
        <%= fp.text_field :product_name %>
      <% end %>
    </p>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

(Note the use of **`fp.label`** instead of **`f.label`** within the `fields_for` block.

The above is from memory so there may be some mistakes (and you'll probably need to change things in your `OrderItemsController` too), but it should give you a starting point.

You might find [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast) helpful too.